# Why does Swipeable not work in my react native code

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm taking the CodeWithMosh react native course, and I'm having trouble getting the `<Swipeable>` component to work on android (I'm on a windows machine). I've  been stuck on this for hours and I've even tried wrapping the component with `<GestureHandlerRootView>` as suggested in an answer  here on stack overflow under a similar question. The solution seemed to work for others, but for some reason it doesn't work for me.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";
import colors from "../config/colors";
import AppText from "./AppText";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import Swipeable from "react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable";


const ListItem = ({ title, subTitle, image, onPress, renderRightActions }) => {
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView>
      <Swipeable renderRightActions={renderRightActions}>
        <TouchableHighlight underlayColor={colors.light} onPress={onPress}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={image} />
            <View>
              <AppText style={styles.title}>{title}</AppText>
              <AppText style={styles.subTitle}>{subTitle}</AppText>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </Swipeable>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
};
```

I tried restarting android studio, restarting the terminal, restarting VSCode.

I even tried importing as `import { GestureHandlerRootView, Swipeable } from "react-native-gesture-handler";`

Comment: what is this function please renderRightActions

Comment: method that is expected to return an action panel that is going to be revealed from the left side when user swipes right__ official docs.

Comment: can you please share your function renderRightActions

Comment: Omg! I just realized  that's where the problem resulted from. The function was `renderRightActions={() => {<ListItemDeleteAction/>}}`  instead of `renderRightActions={() => (<ListItemDeleteAction/>)}`. I feel so dumb. Thanks a whole lot.

Comment: btw you wrote the same function two times, what was your wrong

Comment: The brackets. With curly brackets I have to  use the return  keyword, but with normal brackets,  I don't need to. It's a little  detail, but a very important one, too. Easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are not importing properly

in you code

```
import Swipeable from "react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable";
```

should be like this:

```
import { Swipeable } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
```

btw you dont need this

```
<GestureHandlerRootView>
</GestureHandlerRootView>
```

only your code should be like this:

```
return (
      <Swipeable renderRightActions={renderRightActions}>
        ...
      </Swipeable>
  );
```

Comment: Already did this, didn't work.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Its been over six hours since I've been trying to fix this and I'm very frustrated  at this point. Or could it be an issue  with android studio?

Comment: I've fixed it. The error was coming from my `renderRightActions` function. Thanks a lot for your assistance.

Comment: @BrightKingsley can you tell me what error was coming from renderRightActions ?